# Liferay Portlet Struts action path hook error

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to override "/blogs/view_entry" struts path. Following is the entry in liferay-hook.xml

```
<struts-action>
        <struts-action-path>/blogs/view_entry</struts-action-path>
        <struts-action-impl>com.smb.hook.action.BlogCustomEditAction</struts-action-impl>
</struts-action>
```

Whenever I click on any blog entry in Blogs portlet, It redirects to

> http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home/-/blogs/test-blog-for-testing?_33_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fweb%2Fguest%2Fhome%3Fp_p_id%3D33%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-2%26p_p_col_count%3D2

and blogs portlet becomes invisible.

At console, I can see the test print statement added in render method. After that following error message is logged:

```
ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-22][PortletRequestProcessor:466] Forward does not exist
```

Following are the methods overridden:

```
@Override
    public void processAction(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
            PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("processAction :");
        super.processAction(originalStrutsPortletAction, portletConfig, actionRequest,
                actionResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public String render(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
            PortletConfig portletConfig, RenderRequest renderRequest,
            RenderResponse renderResponse) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("render :");
        return super.render(originalStrutsPortletAction, portletConfig, renderRequest,
                renderResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void serveResource(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
            PortletConfig portletConfig, ResourceRequest resourceRequest,
            ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("serveResource :");
        super.serveResource(originalStrutsPortletAction, portletConfig,
                resourceRequest, resourceResponse);
    }
```

I have tried passing null for originalStrutsPortletAction as shown in one of the example on [liferay dev site](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/overriding-and-adding-struts-actions) but no change in output.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you extend `BaseStrutsPortletAction` (not stated in your snippet).

The default methods of `BaseStrutsPortletAction` do *not* delegate to `originalStrutsPortletAction` - but they delegate to the methods of your class without the `originalStrutsPortletAction`, which are empty in default.

So you have to call `originalStrutsPortletAction` by yourself:

```
@Override
public void processAction(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
        PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {
    originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);
}

@Override
public String render(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
        PortletConfig portletConfig, RenderRequest renderRequest,
        RenderResponse renderResponse) throws Exception {
    return originalStrutsPortletAction.render(portletConfig, renderRequest, renderResponse);
}

@Override
public void serveResource(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
        PortletConfig portletConfig, ResourceRequest resourceRequest,
        ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws Exception {
    originalStrutsPortletAction.serveResource(portletConfig, resourceRequest, resourceResponse);
}
```

Comment: @Tobias I did just like above, but I am getting the exception stating "Set render parameter has already been called" on the line where you are calling the processAction(..). What I am doing is just before this line I am calling  actionResponse.setWindowState(WindowState.NORMAL);

Can you please help?

Comment: Could you please create a new question for this? You should include your stracktrace as well, because it is difficult to help you otherwise.